# Radio button event handlers

Tags: java, eventhandler

I'm having some trouble with a java project. I've made an empty GUI interface, and now I need to add some functionality to it. I'm stuck, however, on how to go about that. The basic layout has 4 radio buttons, Rectangle, Box, Circle, and Cylinder. I have a group panel that has 4 separate panels that each have text boxes with labels for entering height, length, width, and radius. Here's how it looks: [GUI layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at86A.jpg). Depending on the radio button that is selected, certain boxes that aren't needed should be hidden. For example, if Rectangle is selected, only the boxes for length and width should be visible.

The main frame that will display everything is here:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;

public class GUIFrame extends JFrame
{
    //private final BorderLayout layout;
    private final FlowLayout layout;
    private final JLabel lblTitle;
    private final JButton btnProc;

    public GUIFrame()
    {

        super("GUI Layout");
        Font titleFont = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 26);

        btnProc = new JButton("Click to Process");
        lblTitle = new JLabel("Figure Center");
        lblTitle.setFont(titleFont);
        widthPanel myWidth = new widthPanel();
        myWidth.setLocation(0, 400);
        lengthPanel myLength = new lengthPanel();
        heightPanel myHeight = new heightPanel();
        radiusPanel myRadius = new radiusPanel();
        radioButtonPanel myButtons = new radioButtonPanel();

        //layout = new BorderLayout(3, 2);
        layout = new FlowLayout();

        JPanel txtGroup = new JPanel();
        txtGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        txtGroup.add(myWidth);
        txtGroup.add(myLength);
        txtGroup.add(myRadius);
        txtGroup.add(myHeight);
        setLayout(layout);

        add(lblTitle);
        add(myButtons);
        add(txtGroup);
        add(btnProc);


        if(myButtons.btnRectangle.isSelected())
        {
            myHeight.setVisible(false);
            myRadius.setVisible(false);
        }

    }

    private class RadioButtonHandler implements ItemListener
    {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

I can get this working using if statements, but I'm supposed to be using event handlers and I'm lost on how to code that to get it to work properly.

if it helps, here's the code for the button panel:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;


public class radioButtonPanel extends JPanel
{
    private final JRadioButton btnRectangle;
    private final JRadioButton btnBox;
    private final JRadioButton btnCircle;
    private final JRadioButton btnCylinder;
    private final ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup;
    private final JLabel label;
    private final JPanel radioPanel;


    public radioButtonPanel()
    {
        radioPanel = new JPanel();
        radioPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

        btnRectangle = new JRadioButton("Rectangle", true);
        btnBox = new JRadioButton("Box", false);
        btnCircle = new JRadioButton("Circle", false);
        btnCylinder = new JRadioButton("Cylinder", false);
        label = new JLabel("Select A Figure:");
        radioPanel.add(label);
        radioPanel.add(btnRectangle);
        radioPanel.add(btnBox);
        radioPanel.add(btnCircle);
        radioPanel.add(btnCylinder);

        radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        radioButtonGroup.add(btnRectangle);
        radioButtonGroup.add(btnBox);
        radioButtonGroup.add(btnCircle);
        radioButtonGroup.add(btnCylinder);


        add(radioPanel);


    }

}
```

And a sample of one of the panels. They all follow the same setup, just different variable names.

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class heightPanel extends JPanel
{
    private final JLabel lblHeight;
    private final JTextField txtHeight;
    private final JPanel myHeight;

    public heightPanel()
    {
        myHeight = new JPanel();
        myHeight.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        lblHeight = new JLabel("Enter Height:");
        txtHeight = new JTextField(10);
        myHeight.add(lblHeight);
        myHeight.add(txtHeight);


        add(myHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've mistakenly given `radioButtonPanel` in place of the main frame class, can you fix that?

Comment: Didn't realize I did that. Got it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should give you a quick introduction of how to use event `listener/handler` for your button group (`JRadioButtons`).

> but I'm supposed to be using event handlers and I'm lost on how to
>   code that to get it to work properly.

```
    //add listener to the rectangle button and should be the same for the other `JRadioButtons` but with different `identifiers`.

    btnRectangle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           if(e.getSource() == btnRectangle){
          //TODO
           }
        }
    });
```

> Depending on the radio button that is selected, certain boxes that
>   aren't needed should be hidden. For example, if Rectangle is selected,
>   only the boxes for length and width should be visible.

//To hide `JTextFields` use
  `void setVisible(boolean visible)` method. You should pass `false` as the argument to the method if you want to hide the `JTextField`.

**Example:**

```
 btnRectangle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           if(e.getSource() == btnRectangle){
              TextFieldName.setVisible(false); // set the textfields that you want to be hidden once the Rectangle button is chosen.
           }
        }
 });
```

Comment: I think I'm following this, but let me make sure. In the if statement, e.getSource() detects which radio button is selected and calls the setVisible property for the fields I want to false to hide them. Now, is actionPerformed a generic function that catches a change, or should I replace that with something more specific like itemStateChanged?

Comment: Should I make an ActionListener for each button, or can I make a single one with a series of if statements to handle the different buttons? From the way your sample looks, I would guess that each button gets its own ActionListener?

Comment: Yes each with its own , have a look at oracle java reference page for further help. Also if the answer has helped you I would really appreciate if you mark the answer as accepted . Thanks.

Comment: Yes, thank you! You were a huge help. The radio buttons are hiding the appropriate boxes when selected. I just have to get the Process button working bit I want to try that on my own first.

Comment: @Wildfire44601 good to know and good luck!. If you need any help feel free to contact me. ;)